# Setting a rule for a specific character in a password

Tags: javascript

I have to prompt a password for the user and then make sure that the password abides by certain rules.
Some of the rules are easy and some trickier.

I need to make sure that the first character is a uppercase or lowercase letter.

I have tried using the `charAt(0)` function with toLowerCase and toUpperCase
and it works great however it doesn't work if someone inputs a number or special character. It will still give me a true.

```
password.charAt(0) === password.toLowerCase().charAt(0) || password.charAt(0) === password.toUpperCase().charAt(0)
```

I have tried adding a `password.charAt(0) === isNan` but this gives me a false everytime and doesnt work in my condition.

I am not looking for the solution but rather the direction which I should be going towards.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Password rules do not increase security. Its rather the opposite, just saying ...

Comment: What should it return then, when someone enters a special case character? Either way, try using RegEx for your input.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using regex

```js
function checkFirst(input){
  return /[a-z]/i.test(input)
}


console.log(checkFirst('A'))
console.log(checkFirst('a'))
console.log(checkFirst('@'))
```